# JS ondrop event triggered before text input value assigned?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have this basic JS code to trigger a search function when users are typing into the 'string' searchbox, works fine with onkeyup, but I'd like to have the same function when a drag & drop text is dropped on the input.

When I replace .onkeyup with .ondrop it crashes Firefox, and with Ms Edge nothing happens.

```
    document.getElementById('string').ondrop = function(){
     clearTimeout(typingTimer); /*alert(document.getElementById('string').value)*/
     if (document.getElementById('string').value != '') {
      typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping('string', table), doneTypingInterval);
    }
```

The problem seems to be that the text dropped into the input box is not yet assigned as value of the text input at the moment the ondrop event is triggered. alert(document.getElementById('string').value) gives an empty value, and the dropped text doesn't appear in the search box until I close this alert() windows...

I also tried with ondragend but nothing happens (no alert() popup).

Of course it works with .onmouseup,.onclick, .onchange, but an additional click is needed after the drag and drop, which is not very intuitive...

Is there a way to correct this, or to trigger the search on both onkeyup and drag and drop with the same lines ? Or a reason behind this limitation ?

Comment: did you try [oninput event?](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)

Comment: Oninput seems to work perfectly, thanks, I had never heard of that !

Comment: ... the only issue is when I want to trim() the string *only* on "ondrop" and "onpaste" events, not on keyboard input where the final space is most likely voluntary...